# Removing Segmented Controls and start list view from header

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios

i am new on xamarin, i am stuck in this issue from one day, the issue is i have one activity in which i have segmented controls and i just want to remove/hide these segemented controls and in the below segmented controls i have populated the data in listview, now when i programmatically hide or remove the segmented controls, the listview start from the where the segemnted controls hide/remove, the listview not start from the header, below snapshot will give u an exact idea.and i just simply want to that the list view will start from the header, Thanks in advance and any response will be much appreciated.

below is my code:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();


        if (PageViewModel.ShowUShareTab) {
            SegementedControl.InsertSegment("USHARE", 4, false);
        }
        //SegementedControl.Hidden = true
        SegementedControl.RemoveAllSegments();


        UShareTable.RegisterNibForCellReuse(UShareDetailCell.Nib, UShareDetailCell.Key);
        var homeSource1 = new MvxSimpleTableViewSource(UShareTable, UShareDetailCell.Key);
        UShareTable.Source = homeSource1;


        CallDetailsTable.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;

        CallDetailsTable.RegisterNibForCellReuse(CallDetailCell.Nib, CallDetailCell.Key);
        var homeSource = new MvxSimpleTableViewSource(CallDetailsTable, CallDetailCell.Key);
        CallDetailsTable.Source = homeSource;

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<TransactionDetailsView, TransactionDetailsViewModel>();
        set.Bind(homeSource).To(vm => vm.TransactionDetails);
        set.Bind(homeSource1).To(vm => vm.UShareQueryResults);
        set.Bind(SegementedControl).For(t => t.SelectedSegment).To(vm => vm.SelectedSegmented);
        set.Bind(this).For(t => t.Title).To(vm => vm.PageTitle);
        set.Bind(Progress).For(t => t.Visible).To(vm => vm.ProgressBarVisibility);
        set.Apply();

        PageViewModel.PropertyChanged+= PageViewModel_PropertyChanged;

        Add(UShareTable);


        SegementedControl.ValueChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var selectedSegmentId = (sender as UISegmentedControl).SelectedSegment;


            if (selectedSegmentId == 4)
            {
                CallDetailsTable.Hidden = true;
                if (PageViewModel.UShareQueryResults == null || PageViewModel.UShareQueryResults.Count == 0)
                {
                    PageViewModel.LoadUShareQueryData();
                    UShareTable.Hidden = true;
                }
                else {
                    UShareTable.Hidden = false;
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                UShareTable.Hidden = true;
                CallDetailsTable.Hidden = false;
            }

        };

    }
```

This is my Xib file snapshot:

[image]

i have extend the height of the list view but nothing happen below is the snapshot:

[image]

Comment: What is your `UIListView`'s Top constraint like? Is it bound to the bottom of the `UISegmentControl`? Or is it bound to the top of the whole layout?

Comment: @SuavePirate sorry Uilistview is basically UITableView.

Comment: I totally meant to write `UITableView`. My question stands though, what is the top constraint on it?

Comment: @SuavePirate dear thanks alot your hints worked, i have clear all the contraint, and set the listview constarints from the top, and now my UITableview display from top once again thanks :)